# document.getElementById in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web

hey i have some website that work with Explorrer. 
i have to support it on Chrome and FireFox.
when i try to run the site in Chrome i got Error in this line:

the line:

```js
function NavigateSlip(target, linkC) {
 
var l;
try {
    for (x = 1; x <= 11; x++) {
        l = topAppFrame.frames["HMain"].document.getElementById("link" + x);
        l.style.backgroundColor = "#003366";
    }
} catch (e) {

}

   
var linkC = topAppFrame.frames["HMain"].document.getElementById(linkC);
linkC.style.backgroundColor = "red";

topAppFrame.document.frames['SlipArea'].location = target;

}
```

the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

thanks

Comment: Show us the HTML code.

Comment: I assume that you have not added `id` attribute to the element, for which you are trying `getElementById `. It's working in `IE` because if `id` attribute not exist then IE search for `name` attribute, so it's working for IE. But for chrome and FF you must have to specify the `id` attribute.

Comment: what's the value of `linkC` before that line?

Comment: The getElementById() method is supported in all major browsers, including chrome as well as firefox - [Browser Support](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp). Please `console.log(linkC);` and tell me the value of it...

Comment: @WisdmLabs it's about the `document` of the `frame` not being set - FF and Chrome have troubles locating the frame in question or the frame doesn't have a `document` so this in turn becomes `undefined` - `undefined.getElementById('...')` is not supported ^.^

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand can you tell me how to set the document of the frame? thnks

Comment: @uriel well, for that we need to see more code, for instance, what is `topAppFrame`? It is something you defined yourself and as it stands currently I actually doubt that your `topAppFrame` actually has a `frames` array. `window.frames` returns an array of `contentwindow` objects if that is what you're looking for: [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
var linkC = topAppFrame.frames["HMain"].document.getElementById("linkC");
```

If it doesnt work, it would help alot if you show us the other code aswell

Comment: Didn't even see the unquoted `linkC` argument in the `getElementById` call there!

Comment: If that was a problem, I'd expect to see a reference error. It can't be the issue here, because the error message clearly says that `topAppFrame.frames["HMain"].document` is `undefined` so changing the argument you pass to a function which doesn't exist won't help.

Comment: it's didnt help. i puted the whole function